# 301 Loop redirection error after removing .php extension in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

long time ago... when I installed my web-site (actually it was moved from Drupal to WordPress) I decided not to change links and leave them like it is. So they are all now have .php extension (in settings of links I have `/%postname%.php` plus I use .PHP to PAGE plugin). Now I am trying to remove .php and make 301 redirection using .haccess.

First I change settings `/%postname%.php` to `/%postname%`, disable ".PHP to PAGE" plugin... Redirection doesn't work, it gives me loop redirection problem... any idea how to fix it?

p.s. loop happens only when removing .php, if I don't remove .php from link settings all pages redirects to 404

Answer (score 0):

# Remove filename extension

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

```
# To externally redirect /dir/abc.php to /dir/abc
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ $1.php [QSA,NC,L]
```